# Individual patient data meta-analysis with SD's as outcome measure

Tags: standard-deviation, interpretation, meta-analysis

I'm reading the results of an individual patient data (IPD) meta-analysis. The outcomes of the study is expressed in standard deviations (SD's). Comparisons between groups are stated as 0,23 (95% CI 0.15-0.33), SD 0.34, etc. I can't grasp how to interpretate this. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

The point estimate is 0.23.  Any sensible confidence interval for the parameter should include 0.23.  The given confidence interval goes from [0.15, 0.33].  So 0.23 is near the middle.  Generally 95% confidence intervals are reported but the confidence level is not stated.  So you can't be sure, 90% and 99% are also common.  The part where you wrote 0.34 SD's etc. is missing something.  So I do not see how to interpret it.  I might be able to with a more complete quotation. An estimate such as 0.23 (in your case is often given with the CI represented as + or - k standard errors (i.e. standard error is standard deviation of the estimate). But it may be that the estimate and the confidence interval are being expressed in units of standard deviations.

Comment: Yes, the estimates are expressed in units of standard deviations.I copied a piece of the conclusion:, 0.16 (95% CI, 0.07-0.25), and 0.15
(95% CI, 0.07-0.24) SDs lower than sham controls for
back and neck pain, osteoarthritis, and chronic headache,
respectively; the effect sizes in comparison to noacupuncture
controls were 0.55 (95% CI, 0.51-0.58), 0.57
(95% CI, 0.50-0.64), and 0.42 (95% CI, 0.37-0.46) SDs.
These results were robust to a variety of sensitivity analysis....

Comment: I understand the confidence intervals and the point estimates meaning, but don't get the meaning of units of SD's

Comment: @johanna. That is simple. You have a value x and a standard deviation y where x and y are in the same units then x/y puts x into units of standard deviations. So if in the original units the standard deviation is 0.23 then X/0.23 expresses the quantity x in standard deviation units. If you want to see all the inteval endpoints and estimates in the original units just multiple by the standard deviation (in my example you multiple by 0.23).  Is the standard deviation given in the study article?

Comment: Oh, my..My brain can't take this at once. I have to check the article once more.

Comment: One more citation:To give an example of what these
effect sizes mean in real terms, a baseline
pain score on a 0 to 100 scale
for a typical RCT might be 60. Given
a standard deviation of 25, follow-
up scores might be 43 in a noacupuncture
group, 35 in a sham acupuncture
group, and 30 in patients
receiving true acupuncture. If response
were defined in terms of a pain
reduction of 50% or more, response
rates would be approximately 30%,
42.5%, and 50%, respectively.

Comment: And in units of standard deviation theses scores would be 60/25=12/5=2.4, 43/25=1.72 and 30/25 =6/5=1.2.

Comment: Thank you so much...but the conclusion of the article(see above) gives different SD's . Some way the effect sizes mentioned their should match with the examples I just mentioned.They are related.

Comment: Do you get estimates in standard deviation units if you divide the scores by the indicated standard deviations?  Effect size is generally defined as the mean difference /standard deviation of the estimated mean difference.  So effect size can be viewed aas being in standard deviation units.

Comment: Ok. Now I think I get!Stupid.But still I can't make the transformation from effect sizes mentioned and the examples given. But anyway, At least I now understand the expression. Thank you so much!!

Comment: If s$_1$ is the standard error of mean 1 and s$_2$ is the standard error of mean 2 did you take into account that the standard error for the mean difference (given the samples are independent is √[s$_1$$^2$ +s$_2$$^2$] which is bigger than either s$_1$ or s$_2$?